# Create my own street view without using google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view, 360-panorama

I want to create my own street view from 360° panoramas. What I already found is based on google maps and people do this through this site: www.google.com/maps/views but the option of easy creating street view on this site is unavailable from august. So... is there any possibility to create street view (as easy as it is possible) without using google maps? If someone that is a begginer (as me) can do this? Do you have any ideas?